# Trying to display search history with react and the Reddit API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use the reddit API with react so that when the user looks up a subreddit it will display all of the threads from that subreddit along with other info. I'm trying to incorporate a history feature that will display user history and will allow the user to display info from that search when they click on one of their previous searches. In order to do this I created a state variable of an array that will contain all of the users previous searches and a component called history that will take this array and display all of the searches as clickable buttons. However, when I'm trying to import my History component I get an error saying that './History' doesn't contain a default export even though it does and I can't figure out why. 
Here is App.js:

```
import History from './History/History';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      threads: [],
      loading:false,
      previousSearch: []
    };
  }
  handleSearch = async (searchValue) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    let [threads] = await Promise.all([
      getThreads(searchValue)   
    ]);
    console.log(searchValue)

    this.setState({ threads, loading: false, previousSearch:this.state.previousSearch.concat(searchValue)});
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchForm onSearch={this.handleSearch}/>
        {this.state.loading && <Loading />}
        <History previousSearches={this.state.previousSearch}/>
        <div>
        <ThreadList threads={this.state.threads}/>
        </div>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

And here is History.js:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function History(props){
  {props.previousSearches.map((term) => {
   return (
    <button type="button" onClick={this.applyPreviousSearch.bind(this, term)}>
      {term}
    </button>
  );
})}
}
```

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. If there is an issue with your post that requires it to be deleted (and you cannot delete it yourself because there already are answers), please flag it for moderator attention and explain the reason.

Comment: what is your question title?
what is the meaning of "fffffffffffffffffff"

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an error in History.js

This is how it should look

```
export default function History(props) {
    return props.previousSearches.map((term) => {
        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={this.applyPreviousSearch.bind(this, term)}>
              {term}
            </button>
        );
    })
}
```

Also take care binding this because it depends on the context and it's not straightforward to me to understand it in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return from the History.js.

```
import React from 'react';
export default function History(props)  {

     return props.previousSearches.map((term) => { 
          return (
                 <button type="button" onClick={this.applyPreviousSearch.bind(this, term)}> {term} </button> 
          ); 
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to chime in that in addition to what Sergio said it is sometimes helpful to restart your IDE if it's giving you an unexpected error message. Sometimes the IDE's error checking crashes/caches or stops functioning properly and a restart helps.